# How to find the Transaction Status

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, transactionscope

I am using 'TransactionScope', and I need to just do some DML within the C# Code, which I have successfully.

I need to find out that ***what is the status of the Transaction***, that is has it completed successfully or not ?

Because on the basis of the Transaction Status, if the transaction is complete then I need to perform a redirect to another page, otherwise if the transaction is not completed successfully then I need to show the error on the page.


I want to redirect after the following:-

***scope.Complete();***
***scope.Dispose();***

Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you [visit the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) for `TransactionScope`, you would find this well-documented example:

```
try
{
    // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing
    // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work.
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
        {
            // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
            // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
            connection1.Open();

            // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
            returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

            // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting
            // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you
            // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened
            // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.   
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
            {
                // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed
                // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                connection2.Open();

                // Execute the second command in the second database.
                returnValue = 0;
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
            }
        }

        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();

    }

}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

The comment that contains the most value is this one:

> The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown, Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.

So, if no exceptions are thrown, you can continue on. Put your redirect after `scope.Complete()`. If an exception is thrown, the transaction failed and has automatically been rolled back. You could double-check the transaction status (as others have posted) after the call to `Complete()` and before you redirect, via [`Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionstatus.aspx):

```
if (Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed) 
{
    // do redirect
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status`

[Transaction.Current Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx)

[Transaction.TransactionInformation Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioninformation.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
TransactionStatus status = Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best method I've found for capturing this most efficiently / correctly is as follows:

Inside the transactionscope using statement, and before the call to scope/Complete().

```
//Register for the transaction completed event for the current transaction
Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Current_TransactionCompleted);
```

Then create the event handler function as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the TransactionCompleted event of the Current control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed)
    {
        /// Yay it's committed code goes here!
    }
}
```

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted.aspx)

"You can register for this event instead of using a volatile enlistment to get outcome information for transactions. The parameter passed to the TransactionCompletedEventHandler delegate is a Transaction instance. You can then query the TransactionInformation property of the specific instance to get an instance of TransactionInformation, whose Status property contains the status of a transaction with either the Committed or Aborted value."